# Async/await not working on Angular6 on Firebase on get request

Tags: angular, typescript, http, async-await

To get http request I cretaed a function works for check login. But it didn't work properly.

```
async checkLog(mail: string, password: string) {
        let user: User_model;
        await this.http.get('exampleJson').subscribe(async resData => {
            console.log(1); // print 1
            for (let data in resData) {
                await this.http.get<User_model>('exampleJson' + data + '/.json').subscribe(res2Data => {
                    if (mail === res2Data.user_name && password === res2Data.password) {
                        console.log(2); // print2
                        user = res2Data;
                    }
                });
            }
            console.log(3); // print 3
        });
        console.log(4); // print 4
        return user;
    }
}
```

I expect that print 1,2,3,4 but this function returns 4,1,3,2.

And this is my caller code.

```
this.user = await this.userService.checkLog('xyz', '1234');
```

Comment: Please update your post with a question or explain your expectation further.

Comment: I said that I expected print 1 2 3 4 but it's not print like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async / Await don't work with observables (you are trying to await the subscribe there).

If want to keep this logic, you should convert your http observable into promise like:

```js
async checkLog(mail: string, password: string) {
        let user: User_model;
        const resData = await this.http.get('exampleJson').toPromise();
        console.log(1); // print 1
        for (let data in resData) {
                const res2Data = await this.http.get<User_model>('exampleJson' + data + '/.json').toPromise();
                if (mail === res2Data.user_name && password === res2Data.password) {
                        console.log(2); // print2
                        user = res2Data;
                    }
            console.log(3); // print 3
        });
        console.log(4); // print 4
        return user;
    }
}
```